# Creating RDLC reports dynamically w/o XML editing

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc, dynamically-generated

Most would suggest using one of the many XML editors to create a customized RDLC XML, according to user selections, and passing that report to Microsoft's Report Viewer object. I currently implement this method in previous version of my code. However, it is messy, long and lacks eloquence to say the least.

Previous research, I can't remember exactly where I saw it, has led me to believe there is a method to create a data-set, dynamically through code, create an adapter to fill the data-set, and then have that dataset.writeXML() to produce a fully functional copy of XML that can be passed to the Microsoft Report Viewer object.

Again to clarify, I do not want to use XML classes to write my report up. I want to build my dataset through code depending on user selection, have the dataset write out the XML and then pass that to the Reporting object.

A lot of the stuff I've found favors ASP.NET for some reason and I have yet to fully verse myself in its workings.

Comment: Might I mention also, I do not want to create reports prior to runtime and then pipe them into the Reporting object either. It is neccessary in my application to allow the user full ability in column identity, column position, column size... etc. Really I need to know the class I can manipulate, to create an object which will render me XML to pass to the Report Viewer.

Comment: I think I may have found part of my answer, right in front of my face. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252094.aspx

Comment: Apparently what I attempted to describe above when I was talking about not wanted ASP.net references, was my interest in the Windows Form Control and not the Web Services Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I'm trying to do is write out the RDL (Report Definition Language). This RDL is a set of tags that the Microsoft Report Viewer interprets in order to produce a viewable object to the end user. A data-set is an element of that RDL definition so it really can't produce the RDL itself. Kind of like a baby giving birth to a mama. Here are some excellent resources I found that shed insight into the elements of an RDL file. 
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337423%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Its a shame I can't find someway to pass the XML generated by the dataset to the Report Viewer.

Comment: I also found this great walk tutorial for anyone looking into RDLC or report processing in .net. This guy goes through it all in a power point. Pretty sweet.    http://vijays.wordpress.com/2006/12/26/net-rdlc-report-viewer-control/